# Calculating Polsby-Popper Score Using ArcGIS Pro Field Calculator gives ERROR 000539?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, error-000539, typeerror

This operation is using the Field Calculator in ArcGIS Pro 2.1.

I am trying to calculate the [Polsby-Popper Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polsby-Popper_Test) for Congressional Districts.  I have calculated the Geodesic Area and Geodesic Perimeter for each feature using this formula:

```
(12.56637 * !AREA_GEO!) / (!PERIM_GEO! ^ 2)
```

It is returning the error:

> ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in   TypeError: unsupported operand
>   type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'

I am not sure what exactly this error means.

Comment: what type of field are you making the calculations (e.g. float, integer, text, etc.)?

Comment: you want to square !PERIM_GEO!, is that correct? It doesn't like the mixed type, try !PERIM_GEO! * !PERIM_GEO! instead. The value '2' is an integer but !PERIM_GEO! is a float type hence the error message; this operator doesn't do what you think it does in python, it's a bitwise XOR, not an exponent (like C).

Comment: We have a [self-assembling FAQ on ERROR 000539](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000539?sort=frequent).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, your formula should read:

```
(12.56637 * !AREA_GEO!) / (!PERIM_GEO! ** 2)
```

or

```
(12.56637 * !AREA_GEO!) / (!PERIM_GEO! * !PERIM_GEO!)
```

[This page](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators) on python operators shows that the ^ operator is [Bitwise XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR).

Comment: That worked.  Both of the input fields are Doubles and the output field is a float.