# Measuring compactness in Python

Tags: python, geometry, circle, jupyter-notebook, compactness

I have set of polygons whom I would like to check their compactness.

I'm working in Jupyter Notebook and my geometry is GeoPandas.
I would like to try Polsby-Popper test and Schwartzberg test (and other test that are here:  https://fisherzachary.github.io/public/r-output.html ) but I can't find any simple way to do it.

I don't find way to create the necessary circles, e.g "circle whose area is equal to the area of the polygon " or "circle whose circumference is equal to the perimeter of the polygon ".

I have found script to do find smallest enclosing circle but it seems like it works with points and I have polygon in GeoPandas  (https://www.nayuki.io/res/smallest-enclosing-circle/smallestenclosingcircle.py).

If anyone knows any library/package/ any idea of how I can create circles from given perimeter or area. It's important to say that I have around 70k polygons to check so I also have the memory issue.

My end goal is to get ideas how can I calculate this in Python in Jupyter Notebook.

Edit: I have found this library but struggling with install it/use it
(https://jblindsay.github.io/wbt_book/available_tools/gis_analysis_patch_shape_tools.html)
(https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools/blob/master/src/tools/gis_analysis/related_circumscribing_circle.rs)

Comment: You dont need the circle, at least for PP test https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271966/calculating-polsby-popper-score-using-arcgis-pro-field-calculator-gives-error-00

Comment: @BERA I'm forbbiden from use arcgis for this task

Comment: Ofc translate the formula to geopandas. You need geometry area and perimiter length

Comment: @BERA I need to calculate the circumscribing circle , otherwise is just the compactness ratio and not Polsby-Popper test or Schwartzberg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to create circles. The formula is derived from the ratio you mentioned.

Use the following script. You can apply the other formulas easily.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from math import pi, sqrt

def pp_compactness(geom): # Polsby-Popper
    p = geom.length
    a = geom.area    
    return (4*pi*a)/(p*p)
    
def s_compactness(geom): # Schwartzberg
    p = geom.length
    a = geom.area    
    return 1/(p/(2*pi*sqrt(a/pi)))

gdf = gpd.read_file("file/path")
        
gdf["Polsby_Popper"] = gdf.geometry.apply(pp_compactness)
gdf["Schwartzberg"] = gdf.geometry.apply(s_compactness)
    
print(gdf)

#      geometry            Polsby_Popper   Schwartzberg 
#  0   POLYGON ((552...    0.351956        0.593259  
#  1   POLYGON ((552...    0.550202        0.741756  
#  ..               ...         ...             ...  
#  130 POLYGON ((553...    0.434469        0.659142  
#  131 POLYGON ((553...    0.706016        0.840248
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, if I understand from you, I missunderstood the calclation and the calculation is the polygon with itself and not with circles?

Comment: The formula is derived from the ratio you mentioned. Don't worry about the ratio. There is a similar derivation in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/374058/29431).